Use of the package 'bodeplot' giving warnings and doesn't produce the plot
I am just a beginner and am writing my first report in LaTeX, so excuse me if the solution is very obvious. I am trying to plot asymptotic approximation of bode plots using the package bodeplot as answered here, I simply copied and pasted the following sample code as give in the documentation,
\begin{BodeMagPlot}[%
  axes/{height=2cm,
  width=4cm}
]
{0.01}
{100}
  \addBodeZPKPlots[%
     asymptotic/{blue,dotted,thick}%
 ]
{magnitude} 
{%
  z/{0,{-0.1,-0.5},{-0.1,0.5}},
  p/{{-0.5,-10},{-0.5,10}},
  k/10%
}
\end{BodeMagPlot}

Now if I am using Overleaf to compile, I am getting the expected results, but then when I use the exact syntax in MikTeX installed on my PC, I do not get any plot, and instead, two warnings messages are displayed:

\ifplatform.sty:0:shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect
\ifwindows


You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). Replacing it with
a default range and clearing all plots

As far as I can tell the second warning is why I didn't get any plot, but I couldn't understand how to rectify this by giving the range for y-axis, and why does this run in Overleaf, but not on my system? And if the first warning is responsible for this somehow.

Welcome! Overleaf compiles your document in a sandbox and enables unrestricted shell-escape because the sandbox makes that safe. TeX distributions don't enable unrestricted shell-escape by default because it is a security vulnerability. So you need to compile this document with shell-escape. For TeX Live, it would be -shell-escape or --shell-escape. MikTeX has a similar option, but I think it might be differently named. (If you are using LuaTeX, it gets a tiny bit more complicated, but this is sufficient for other engines.)

What I was missing here was that the package uses GNUplot rather than pgf, installing GNUplot resolved the issue.

Like the comment says, you need to invoke LaTeX with the --shell-escape flag.
pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex

The other option is to use native pgf instead of gnuplot to do the computations. External commands (i.e., --shell-escape) are needed only for gnuplot. If you do not use gnuplot, then you do not need --shell-escape.
To do this, use the bodeplot package withe the pgf option:
\usepackage[pgf]{bodeplot}

The use of lualatex is recommended if you use native pgf to do calculations.
